# ADO.NET Funny Connection Pool Behaviour when bury SQL Exception

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am catching a sql exception and not rethrowing it. This seems to mean that the connection is not returned to the pool as I would expect. Is this possible?

```
        using (IDbCommand paymentCommand = this.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                //database stuff
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
               //LOG CALL
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you expect the connection to be returned to the pool in this situation? You're not explicitly closing/disposing it, and it's not wrapped in a `using` block.

Comment: You should show us the code where you're initializing and closing  the connection(using-statement?). In general, a using-statement does not only call dispose when an unhandled exception occured but always, so your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you put using(...){} inside try{} block? This way even if exception is thrown, using block will dispose off IDBcmd obj.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear in your question how you are creating the connection, but you do need to make sure you Open it, then Close it, regardless of errors or not.

Typically I'll do something like this:

```
SqlConnection connection = null;
try {
    connection.Open();

    // Do stuff like run a query, setup your IDbCommand, etc.
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Log error
} finally {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

This way, no matter what happens, your connection will be closed and returned to the pool. If you fail to Close(), you'll "leak" that connection and eventually run out of pooled connections to draw from. The lifetime of the connection should generally only be as long as it takes to issue your sql command, at which point you should be closing it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are experiencing with the connection pool. However, I would **definitely wrap your connection in a `using` statement**.

This is what I usually use (note that `dac.GetConnection()` is simply a class that centralizes the code to get a connection object):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = dac.GetConnection())
{
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("myProc", connection))
  {
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    try
    {
      connection.Open();           
      //add params, run query

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      //handle/log errror
    }
    finally
    {
      if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        connection.Close();
    }
  }
}
```